Automapper .ForMember issue: Expression 'dest => dest' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties
I'm trying to map the result of a GroupJoined DB query into a Dto with Automapper. The query returns a docket list with two related deadlines for each docket as anonymous type { Docket, DateTime?, DateTime? }.
I tried to map them like this:
configuration.CreateMap<(Docket docket, DateTime? deadline, DateTime? internalDeadline), DocketDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.docket))
    .AfterMap((a, b) =>
    {
        b.NextDeadline = a.deadline;
        b.NextInternalDeadline = a.internalDeadline;
    });

But it causes an error "Expression 'dest => dest' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead. (Parameter 'lambdaExpression')".
So I tried with ForPath:
configuration.CreateMap<(Docket docket, DateTime? deadline, DateTime? internalDeadline), DocketDto>()
    .ForPath(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.docket))
    .AfterMap((a, b) =>
    {
        b.NextDeadline = a.deadline;
        b.NextInternalDeadline = a.internalDeadline;
    });

This causes an error "Only member accesses are allowed. dest => dest (Parameter 'destinationMember')"
DocketDto has matching properties for Docket, and the two additional DateTime? properties NextDeadline and NextInternalDeadline.
Is there a way to automap this, or maybe a better way while selecting the result? This is how it's selected/mapped after querying:
IQueryable<GetDocketForView> query = (from o in docketsWithDeadlines
    select new GetDocketForView()
    {
        Docket = ObjectMapper.Map<DocketDto>(o),
    });


anonymous type { Docket, DateTime?, DateTime? }, but in your Mapper Configuration: (Docket docket, DateTime? deadline, DateTime? internalDeadline). It is a tuple which is not the anonymous type you provided.
